# SMOTE over sampling applied on text classification

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on text classification, where I am using Multinominal Naive Bayes Classifier to predict article titles into their respective subject categories. Both of these are stored in a pandas data frame and are text columns. However they're are two categories which contain 50,000 records and 30,000 records respectively. Hence I need to do oversampling of the data and then apply the algorithm. When I do oversampling it reduces the model accuracy score and give me 15%. Please tell me how I can improve it.

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test=train_test_split(df['Title'],df['Subjects'], test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)


sm = SMOTE(random_state=2)
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_sample(X_train_tfidf, Y_train)
print("Shape after smote is:",X_train_res.shape,y_train_res.shape)

nb = Pipeline([('clf', MultinomialNB())])
nb.fit(X_train_res, y_train_res)
y_pred = nb.predict(count_vect.transform(X_test))
print(accuracy_score(Y_test,y_pred))
```

I expect to increase model accuracy by doing so. Model accuracy without oversampling is 62% and after oversampling is 15%, when it should actually be higher.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using SMOTE for balancing/oversampling classes can be problematic in text classification tasks. There are nice explanations and suggestions for alternatives here:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27758

In short, the SMOTE output may not represent "meaningful" substitutes and due to the size of the feature space its nearest-neighbor based approach may yield poor results.

Some more ideas:

- Instead of using accuracy, it is advisable to use F1 or similar.
- Rather unlikely to help but did you try undersampling?
- For the MultinomialNB classifier you might try setting `class_prior` explicitly.
- Finally, other methods like Forests and Boosting approaches might be better suited for imbalanced datasets.